# Limit App to only iPad 1

Tags: ios, ipad, deployment, operating-system, limit

I have an app that has been in the store for a while now. I am coming out with a completely new app to replace the old one but it is not compatible with the original iPad (iPad 1). I don't want to completely get rid of the original app because, believe it or not, there is still a large number of people running it on iPad 1's. Is there a way to somehow set up either the app or the app store to where users who have newer iPads only see the new app in the app store and not the old one? (They have different titles, icons, etc)

Comment: sergio and WDUK both give the technical ways to limit access to the iPad 1 but I would like to add an important note and that is to make it very obvious that you are dropping support of that device because of important features that are impossible to back port. Unfortunately the update will still appear for people with iPad 1's and it will give a popup to them telling them they need a new version of iOS or device and it can anger them to leave bad reviews and comments.

Comment: Good point in general, but he was saying that he's putting out "a new app", not an update to the existing one... more like a 'sequel'. So the iPad 1 people won't get that update-prompt.

Comment: FOLLOW-UP: So I can use the require capabilities trick so that customers with iPad 1's don't see the new app, but is there any way that customers with newer iPads can't see the old app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: it seems that [you cannot change the capabilities of an already published app](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/uirequireddevicecapabilities-cannot-be-changed-in-app-updates/) when you submit a new version. This would rule out the first approach I suggested and leave only limiting the current deployment target.

You could require a device capability not available on the iPad 1, like the camera.

This amounts to setting [`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3) in your app plist file to `front-facing-camera`.

Another option you would have, in case the former one did not work, is setting your deployment target to iOS 6 -- this would also rule out the iPad 1s (and all devices running iOS 4 and 5).

Comment: iOS6 only option would be beneficial for the developer as well. Good suggestion.

Comment: @WDUK: thanks, additionally I found out that you cannot change the capabilities of an already published app... see my edited answer for a reference.

Comment: Thank you both for the great answers! I haven't published this new app yet though and it isn't really "an update" to the app thats out now. It is really a whole new app but it contains the capabilities that the original one has so it wouldn't make sense for any customer to have both.

Comment: FYI: If you require certain device capabilities, then your app *must* use them. Abusing device capabilities to avoid having to support a certain model will likely cause your app to be rejected.

Comment: I actually have a nice feature that I would love to incorporate using the front-camera so I can definitely do that. Thanks @DaveDeLong.